# Merging vertices and other tools ignoring SubSurf in 2.80

Tags: modifiers, vertices, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to connect two shapes in blender but whenever I try to connect the vertices, whether it's through merging them individually (alt + m), using the bridge tool, or through Remove Doubles (now called Merge by Distance), the vertices behave as if they aren't being affected by the subsurf modifier. Here's the shape without the modifier on:
[image: Model without subsurf]

And here it is with the modifier on:
[image]

Turning the modifier off or removing it, merging the vertices, then adding the modifier back still causes the same error. I assume this is a bug but I want to know if there's something I'm missing. In the meantime I suppose I'll have to model the entire shape as one piece.

Comment: Can you upload the .blend file (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? I suspect there are still duplicate vertices / edge loops hiding there or an internal face.

Comment: I went ahead and modeled the base as one solid shape but I'll see if I can replicate the error in a new file.

Comment: [Here's the mockup I made.](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6338/)

Answer (score 1):

The normals were flipped. Recalculating the normals using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> fixes it.

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

Comment: That worked, thanks! Now I'm wondering how the normals got flipped to begin with.

Comment: @NdieCIty, did you make half and then duplicate and scale by -1? that will do it.